# PHP - backspace in file with fwrite

Tags: php, file, fwrite, backspace

I can't put a backspace in a File I try with:

```
fwrite($file, "\tpublic static function byPk(");
foreach ($pk as $column)
    fwrite($file, "\$" . $column->name . ", ");
fwrite($file, "\x08");
```

But the result in the file is:

[image]

Any solution? Thanks! :D

Comment: Can you `var_dump($column->name)` so we can see what's in there? Looks like a problem in charsets

Comment: is a simple string like "user", or "comment" or "sale"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use fseek() to go backward. http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fseek.php

You can also make an array with your columns names and implode them.

Comment: And if is another way? What happend if is in the end of file?? and I want to remove the last character?

Is possible to make a backspace ??

Comment: In your case it will never be the end of file because you need to backward 2 characters and add a parenthesis... If the parenthesis is the end simply add a whitespace after ?
EDIT: It's not possible to 'backspace' because it's a character too...

Comment: So the best way is put all string in a $var and cut the string and put in the fwrite o: ??

Comment: And what do u think is the best way in efficiencity?

Comment: I think do: fseek($file, -2, SEEK_END ) before writing fwrite($file, ")")

Comment: Thanks! I go to use that :D